# PowerShell exception with UploadFile

Tags: powershell, ftp, webclient, powershell-3.0, ftp-client

I am trying to copy a file from my local to ftp, using the following code.

```
$ftpname = ftp://xxx/xxx/file1.txt
$localfilepath = "C:\Outbox\file1.txt"
$ftpusername = "xxx"
$ftppassword = "xx"

$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

$client.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($ftpusername,$ftppassword)

return $client.UploadFile($ftpname, $localfilepath)
```

I am getting "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."

I am well able to access the ftp in browser via same proxy settings.
Is this something to do with proxy settings ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the string that's being assigned to $ftpname missing quotes in your actual code, or just your example?

What you could try is changing

```
$ftpname = ftp://xxx/xxx/file1.txt
```

to this

```
$ftpname = New-Object System.Uri('ftp://xxx/xxx/file1.txt')
```

The UploadFile() method has a few overloaded versions, one of which is UploadFile(URI, string). Would be interesting to see if it behaves differently. Other than that it could be network settings